# Displaying multiple names from different objects from a query in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, custom-object

I have three different custom objects. LGFProduct__c, PartsinProducts__C, and Part__c. They are in a many-to-many relationship and PartsinProducts__c is the junction object.

Currently my SOQL query is:

```
[SELECT name,id, (SELECT LGFProduct__r.name, LGFProduct__r.id FROM PartsinProducts__r WHERE LGFProduct__r.Name  =: ProductName) FROM Part__c ];
```

A product is already selected on the current page and only parts that are related to the product should show. However, currently it is displaying all products, which leads me to believe my visual force page is displaying the name of the Parts and not the name of the PartsinProduct or the location of my where is incorrect.

My controller is:

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    public String ProductName {get;set;}
    public List<Part__c> parts { get; private set; }

    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        ProductName  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('LGFProduct__c.name');
        parts = [SELECT name,id, (SELECT LGFProduct__r.name, LGFProduct__r.id FROM PartsinProducts__r WHERE LGFProduct__r.Name  =: ProductName) FROM Part__c ];

    }
}
```

My Visualforce page is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Service_Case__c" extensions="MyExtension">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!parts}" var="part">
            <apex:column value="{!part.Name}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!part.id}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I have tried setting **{!part.name}** to **{!part__r.Partsinproduct__r.name}** in VF and was given the error:

```
Unknown property 'Service_Case__cStandardController.part__r'
```

If the error is by chance the location of the where is wrong and instead the where should be outside of the PartsinProducts__r and after part__c how would I make the relationship as I am thrown an error if I just try:

```
parts = [SELECT name,id, (SELECT LGFProduct__r.name, LGFProduct__r.id FROM PartsinProducts__r) FROM Part__c WHERE LGFProduct__r.Name  =: ProductName]
```

Comment: Try using a <apex:repeat> and use this for the value: `{!part.Partsinproduct__r}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, the SOQL statement will retrieve all Parts because that is in the outermost select - there is no WHERE clause filtering Parts

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
 public String ProductName {get;set;}
 public List<Part__c> parts { get; private set; }

 public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
 {
    ProductName  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('LGFProduct__c.name');
    parts = [SELECT name,id, 
               (SELECT LGFProduct__r.name, LGFProduct__r.id 
                 FROM PartsinProducts__r 
                 WHERE LGFProduct__r.Name  =: ProductName)
            FROM Part__c ];
 }
}
```

what it looks like you need is to come at it from the other side of the junction object - namely the `LGFProduct__c` object that presumably represents a Product.

```
public PartsInProduct__c[] partsInProducts {get; private set;}
partsInProducts = [SELECT name,id, 
               (SELECT Part__r.name, Part__r.id 
                 FROM PartsinProducts__r 
                 )
            FROM LGFProduct__c where name = :ProductName ][0].PartsinProducts__r;
```

Since you just want a list of Part__c objects, you need to dereference the SOQL result - which is an `LGFProduct__c` to the list of children `PartsInProducts`.

Then, your VF would be:

```
<apex:page standardController="Service_Case__c" extensions="MyExtension">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!partsInProducts}" var="pip">
            <apex:column value="{!pip.Part__r.Name}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!pip.Part__r.id}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

This all assumes that the relationship name from `LGFProduct__c` to `PartsInProducts__c` is called `PartsInProducts__r` and that the lookup relationship from `PartsInProduct__c` to `Part__c` is called `Part__r`. Adjust the answer accordinlgy to your values if different

Comment: I changed Part__r.name.id to just Part__r.id because it was giving me an error. But after changing it,  there is no error on the developer console but an error is thrown on the preview or VF page. The error is: "Content cannot be displayed: List index out of bounds: 0." Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: that would be because `LGFProduct__c where name = :ProductName ][0]` isn't returning  a match between the param `ProductName` and the `LGFProduct__c`