# List index out of bounds error

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, custom-object

When trying out a proposed solution to my previous question, [Displaying multiple names from different objects from a query in VF](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138763/displaying-multiple-names-from-different-objects-from-a-query-in-vf), while there is no error in the developer console, I am receiving an error when I preview the page. The query without the where portion gets me the data I need (I tested it without the where portion in the query editor), but I believe there is an issue stemming from the **where** portion of the query.
The controller is:

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    public String ProductName {get;set;}
    public List<Part__c> parts { get; private set; }
    public PartsInProduct__c[] partsInProducts {get; private set;}


    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        ProductName  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('LGFProduct__c.name');
        //parts = [SELECT name,id, (SELECT LGFProduct__r.name, LGFProduct__r.id FROM PartsinProducts__r WHERE LGFProduct__r.Name  =: ProductName) FROM Part__c ];
        partsInProducts = [SELECT name, id, 
               (SELECT Part__r.name, Part__r.id 
                 FROM PartsinProducts__r 
                 )
            FROM LGFProduct__c where name = :ProductName ][0].PartsinProducts__r;//Part where I believe error occurs
    }
}
```

**How do I make the array index in bounds?**

I understand what an array out of bounds error is but what I don't get is the line:

```
FROM LGFProduct__c where name = :ProductName ][0].PartsinProducts__r;
```

Doesn't the query end after the ] bracket? What is the purpose and meaning of the [0].PartsinProducts__r? I think my issue stems from my lack of understanding of this line of code. Is there nothing in the array? I'm quite sure 0 index of an array indicates the first element in that array.

The controller can be seen in the link but I will put it here anyways:

```
<apex:page standardController="Service_Case__c" extensions="MyExtension">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!partsInProducts}" var="pip">
            <apex:column value="{!pip.Part__r.Name}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!pip.Part__r.id}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

This is the error message I get from the two huge code blocks above: 
[image]

The query that I run in the query editor and its results:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        ProductName  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('LGFProduct__c.name');
        //parts = [SELECT name,id, (SELECT LGFProduct__r.name, LGFProduct__r.id FROM PartsinProducts__r WHERE LGFProduct__r.Name  =: ProductName) FROM Part__c ];
        partsInProducts = [SELECT name, id, 
               (SELECT Part__r.name, Part__r.id 
                 FROM PartsinProducts__r 
                 )
            FROM LGFProduct__c where name = :ProductName ][0].PartsinProducts__r;//Part where I believe error occurs
    }
```

Will throw an List Index Out of bounds error if no records are returned.

You example of `FROM LGFProduct__c where name = :ProductName ];` will not result in a "List has not rows for assignment" error if your code in as you have it in your example:

```
public PartsInProduct__c[] partsInProducts {get; private set;}
```

So I am a bit confused on what your code looks like when you get an which error.

As for the

> Doesn't the query end after the ] bracket? What is the purpose and
>   meaning of the [0].PartsinProducts__r?

The [0] is the index of the records returned. If no records are returned then the list is empty. Empty lists have NO indexes at all and [0] will result in a list index out of bounds error.

So you need to ensure that when you query you assign the results to a list type and check for it being empty before working with it.

Liberal use of debugs will help you find your issue. Likely the get param is returning null

Comment: If I change PartsinProduct__c to a list, I get an illegal list to list assignment. That was what I was trying to state. But if the get parameter is returning null, is there some syntax error I am not aware of? I'm quite sure there is a Product on the page, so I'm not sure why it's returning null.

Comment: I did update the question so that the code that I was using is more clear.

Comment: And the issue is still the same, no records are returned from your query and you are blindly using `[0].xxxxxx`

Comment: Well that's was kind of what I was trying to say, it was suggested to me by an answer and I have no idea what it meant. The query works fine though without the where and I placed an example above, so I am confused as to whether the get parameter is returning null or my query not working because of the where?

Comment: read the last line of my answer :)

Comment: Okay thanks! I was previously a bit confused. Is there anything you see wrong with my syntax for the get parameter?

Comment: Not sure if `LGFProduct__c.name` is a valid value given the period (.) and even if it is it is not the best format for a URL parameter. Unfortunately only you can answer this as it is your org and your process so the answer is unique to your code